# Don't undertand this missing 1 required positional argument error

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my initlialize() function I create a variable for a file:

```
def initialize():
    # Set the output file
    output_dir="../../../output_files/aws_instance_list/"
    output_file = output_dir + "aws-master-list-" + today +'.csv'
    return output_file
```

I'm trying to pass the output file to the loop_regions() function:

```
def loop_regions(output_file):
    csv_file = open(output_file, mode='a+')
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
    loop_regions()
TypeError: loop_regions() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output_file'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you call `loop_regions` ?

Comment: As the errors says, that functions expects an argument, and you aren't supplying it. It looks like you intended to pass the file that `initialize` returns.

Comment: I call loop regions in the main body of my script: `loop_regions()`. I am going to build that part of the script into the main function, but I have not gotten that far yet.

Comment: if you call `loop_regions()`, you're calling it with 0 arguments. In your definition, you tell it to expect a single argument, called `output_file`. pass `loop_regions` an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
def loop_regions():
    output_file = initialize()
    csv_file = open(output_file, mode='a+')
```

Also, if you're on Windows, you can reduce your initialize() method using the os module:

```
import os
def initialize():
    # Set the output file
    output_dir = r'C:\..\..\..\output_files\aws_instance_list'
    return os.path.join(output_dir, 'aws-master-list-' + today + '.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `loop_regions(output_file)` but you're calling it like `loop_regions()`. Doing something like `loop_regions(initialize())` will make it work or assigning the result of `initialize` to a variable and passing that into `loop_regions`.

Just note that the fact you named two different things `output_file` doesn't bind them together.